# How to make an horizontal scroll section with not fixed item width

Tags: css

I've created this example:

```css
.container {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.card {
  min-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.card-final {
  padding-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">Cat</div>
  <div class="card">Tropical fish</div>
  <div class="card">Southern Titiwangsa bent-toed gecko</div>
  <div class="card">Woodpecker</div>
  <div class="card">Crow</div>
  <div class="card">Peacock</div>
  <div class="card">Pig</div>
  <div class="card">Dog</div>
  <div class="card-final"></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to have is that the `.card`s have no fixed width the text inside each card should be on a single line and each card shouldn't have more horizontal space that the necessary. So the `Pig` card will have smaller width than then the `Tropical fish` card or the `Southern Titiwangsa bent-toed gecko` card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `min-width` and use `flex-shrink:0;`

```css
.container {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.card-final {
  padding-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">Cat</div>
  <div class="card">Tropical fish</div>
  <div class="card">Southern Titiwangsa bent-toed gecko</div>
  <div class="card">Woodpecker</div>
  <div class="card">Crow</div>
  <div class="card">Peacock</div>
  <div class="card">Pig</div>
  <div class="card">Dog</div>
  <div class="card-final"></div>
  <div class="card">Crow</div>
  <div class="card">Peacock</div>
  <div class="card">Pig</div>
  <div class="card">Dog</div>
  <div class="card">Crow</div>
  <div class="card">Peacock</div>
  <div class="card">Pig</div>
  <div class="card">Dog</div>
</div>
```